# bundle exec rake db:create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Keep getting this when I run `bundle exec rake db:create`:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what database are you using? Postgres?

Comment: Did you run postgresql server?

Comment: Yes using Postgres db. Trying to run this app: github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr

Comment: yeah, that's embarrassing. I didn't have the server running hahaha. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because of a permission issue. Navigate to `/etc/postgresql/<your version of pg>/main/` and open up pg_hba.conf.

There search for a line that'd say 
`local    all    postgres    peer` and replace it to `local     all    all    trust`.
Then run `sudo service postgresql restart` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

It will work

your `database.yml` should look like this :

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <DATABASE_NAME>
  pool: 5
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

And it will be same for another environments

Comment: Still getting the same error. I am trying to run this application if that helps at all: https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr

Comment: Have you added this : port: 5432 in database.yml